# Android ConnectionService with specific useTargetVersion & minTargetVersion

Tags: android, voip-android

I'm new on Android development and curious about ConnectionService. I see a doc and it mention that it's coming from Android API 23. If my project use useTargetVersion=25 and minTargetVersion=16, can I still use ConnectionService? Can it guarantee that it's working on Android API 16 device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work on API less than 23. You'll need to check Android API version in app before using it to see if it is compatible.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
  // Use ConnectionService()
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

You can also avoid lint issues by using the decorator

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
```

over the method in question.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/annotation/TargetApi.html